# Rails 5 mailer Net::SMTPFatalError when sending email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I built a very basic contact form to allow people to send me an email. This is all just part of learning for me so it's not a production site. When the user inputs their information and clicks the "send" button it appears to go through then a a few seconds to a minute later I get the following kick back.

```
Net::SMTPFatalError (554 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException
.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied; Failed to process message due to a permanent 
exception with message Cannot submit message. 16.55847:6D0F0000, 
17.43559:0000000004020000000000000100000000000000, 
20.52176:140FC3870D00F01FCB030000, 20.50032:140FC3877D17401080030400, 
0.35180:D0030000, 255.23226:0A007680, 255.27962:0A000000, 
255.27962:0E000000, 255.31418:1F000130, 16.55847:A6000000, 
17.43559:00000000E0020000000000000100000000000000, 
20.52176:140FC3870D00401080030400, 20.50032:140FC3877D1710103A000000, 
0.35180:03000136, 255.23226:21000000, 255.27962:0A000000, 
255.27962:32000000, 255.17082:DC040000, 0.27745:44000000, 
4.21921:DC040000, 255.27962:FA000000, 255.1494:49000000, 0.38698:00000000, 
0.37692:1A010480, 0.37948:00000600, 5.33852:00000000534D545000010480, 
4.56248:DC040000, 7.40748:010000000000010B31333A4D, 
7.57132:00000000000000003A343731, 1.63016:32000000, 4.39640:DC040000, 
8.45434:2653E8C6336A0D409107BFF092BEB44600000000, 
5.10786:0000000031352E32302E313938372E3031333A4D5748505231374D42313433383A3437
3161356633312D326662322D346661312D383035372D3464363739346338313461300040101A010480, 255.1750:9D000000, 255.31418:80000000, 0.22753:03000236, 
255.21817:DC040000, 4.60547:DC040000, 0.21966:03001736, 4.30158:DC040000 
[Hostname=MWHPR17MB1438.namprd17.prod.outlook.com]
):

app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:11:in `create'
```

The code I have seems to be right and I believe the issue lies within the smtp settings, can someone confirm this? I'm using office365 through godaddy and I see a lot of people struggling to get it working.

**message_mailer.rb**

```
class MessageMailer < ApplicationMailer
default from:  ENV['SMTP_EMAIL']
# Subject can be set in your I18n file at config/locales/en.yml
# with the following lookup:
#
#   en.message_mailer.contact_me.subject
#
def contact_me(message)

    @body = message.message_body

    mail to: ENV['SMTP_EMAIL'], from: message.email_address
  end
end
```

**messages_controller.rb**

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  def new
      @message = Message.new
  end

  def create
      @message = Message.new(message_params)

      if @message.valid?
          MessageMailer.contact_me(@message).deliver_now
          redirect_to new_message_url, notice: "Message received"
      else
          render :new
      end
  end

  private

      def message_params
          params.require(:message).permit(:name, :email_address, :message_body)
      end

end
```

**message.rb**

```
class Message
    include ActiveModel::Model

    attr_accessor :name, :email_address, :message_body

    validates :name, :email_address, :message_body, presence: true
end
```

**app/views/messages/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @message, url: create_message_url do |f| %>
    <%= notice %>
    <%= @message.errors.full_messages.join(', ') %>

    <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: 'Name' %>
    <%= f.email_field :email_address, placeholder: 'Email address' %>
    <%= f.text_area :message_body, placeholder: 'body' %>
    <%= f.submit 'Send' %>
```

**config/environments/development.rb**

```
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
      :host => "localhost:3000"
  }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      address:              'smtp.office365.com',
      port:                 587,
      user_name:            ENV['SMTP_EMAIL'],
      password:             ENV['SMTP_PASS'],
      authentication:       :login,
      enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by making the following changes and will accept this answer when the timers up!

**/config/environment.rb**

```
# Load the Rails application.
require_relative 'application'
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :sendmail # Added this line
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {           # Added this line
    :domain  => 'localhost'                    # Added this line
}                                              # Added this line
# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!
```

**/config/environments/development.rb**

```
 config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
 config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
      :host => "localhost"                   # Removed port
 }
 config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
 config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
 config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address => 'smtp.office365.com',
      :port => 587,
      :domain => 'localhost',                # Added domain and set to localhost
      :authentication => :login,
      :user_name => ENV['SMTP_EMAIL'],
      :password => ENV['SMTP_PASS'],
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
   }
```